# How to link to nested resources in Ember.js?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Assume you have the following routes in an Ember application.

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('series', function() {
    this.resource('serie', { path: '/:serie_id' }, function() {
      this.resource('seasons', function() {
        this.resource('season', { path: '/:season_id' }, function() {
          this.resource('episodes', function() {
            this.resource('episode', { path: '/:episode_id' });
          })
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

How would I link to a specific **episode** using the `linkTo` helper that Handlebars provides? In other words, how does Ember figure out what the other parameters of the URL should be, that is, the `serie_id` and `episode_id`? The documentation states that I should pass an `episode` model to the `episode` route as shown below.

```
{{#linkTo "episode" episode}}
```

This is to link to the following URL structure.

```
/series/:serie_id/seasons/:season_id/episodes/:episode_id/
```

When I use the `linkTo` helper like that, Ember throws an error telling me that it cannot call `get` with `id` on `undefined`. I assume that it uses the `episode` model to figure out what the `serie_id` and `episode_id` are and my guess is that the model needs to conform to a specific convention (structure or blueprint) for Ember to find these `id`s.

These are the aspects that I find most difficult about Ember. It isn't very transparent even if you use Ember in debug mode. Any pointers or references are much appreciated.

**UPDATE 1: After some digging, I found out that the route's `serialize` method is a key element in accomplishing this. However, when I use the `linkTo` helper as illustrated above, the model passed to the route's `serialize` method is `undefined` for some reason (even though it is not when passed to the `linkTo` helper. The question that led to this discovery can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15698253/passing-a-dynamic-parameter-different-than-xyz-id-using-linkto-in-ember-js).**

**UPDATE 2: It turns out that the `serieSeason` route's `serialize` method receives the wrong model, an episode instead of a season, when the link is generated. It isn't clear, though, why it is receiving the wrong model. Where does the `model` parameter of the `serialize` method come from?**

**UPDATE 3: The `linkTo` helper works fine if I return static data from the `serialize` method of each route involved, which means that the `linkTo` helper isn't involved in the problem.**

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It turns out that the answer could be found in the properly documented source of Ember ... because that is what one does after searching the web for several days.

The answer is simple. **The `linkTo` helper accepts more than one model.** For each dynamic segment of the destination URL, you pass a corresponding model. Each passed model will become the model of the corresponding route in the destination URL. In the example that I describe above, this results in the following.

```
{{#linkTo "episode" serie season episode}}
```

The `serie` model will be passed to the `serie` route, the `season` model to the `season` route, and the `episode` model to the `episode` route. What confuses many developers is that the route's `model` hook isn't triggered when you use the `linkTo` helper. This isn't too surprising if you realize that the developer provides (or can provide) the model for the corresponding route by passing one or more models (or zero).

Because there isn't much documentation for deeply nested resources, it wasn't trivial to find out how the `linkTo` helper does its job under the hood. Diving in Ember's source definitely helps getting up to speed with the framework.

Comment: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#toc_supplying-multiple-models

Maybe this was not there by the time you asked this question...

Comment: @LucasPottersky Nor is it now!